# how to create "has many" between two documents in couchdb?

Tags: java, couchdb

basically I am wondering how you would go about in Couchdb as you would in MysQL: storing username, password in one table and link the user id as foreign key on another table of tasks?

should I just use mysql for the user authentication part and couchdb to store lots of user submitted documents? so create a random unique token to link each user to their "documents" on couchdb?

also I am looking to store Java objects to the couchdb, and retrieve them to be used directly in my  application. which Java-couchdb library does this? Ektorp's example is seems more complicated compared to couchdb4j.

Comment: This is a good question. (I wish more people discussed and used Java with CouchDB.) However, you could improve it more by asking two questions: one is about "has many" and another about Java. However I answered both below, to save time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know Java very well, but I suggest use the most **simple** tool you find. CouchDB is very **simple** and usually it is most beneficial to access it with simple tools too.

Yes, if you will have many relationships in the data, MySQL will help. However CouchDB can do some simple has-many queries.

First, there is [view collation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation). You use map/reduce, and for every "child" document, you emit a key pointing to the parent document. When you query for `?key=parent` then you get a long list of children. (The wiki explains it pretty well.)

Secondly, I suggest the article [What's new in CouchDB 0.11](http://blog.couchbase.com/whats-new-in-apache-couchdb-0-11-part-two-views) which shows how to use document _ids to link between two documents.

Good luck!

Comment: I've begun using Mongodb....it just seems more polished and more features. I was up and running in matter of seconds compared to couchdb which took some tinkering. Can has many be achieved in mongodb?

Comment: Cool! "Up and running quickly" is a very important priority. I am not sure about MongoDB however I believe it has an active Stack Overflow community. If you start another question, they will be very helpful. Good luck!